# Word cluster for jobs where people perform the functions of

Tags: professions

What are the words for jobs where people perform the following functions :

Classifying things, cataloguing things, annotating things, organizing things.

I thought of things like : natural historian, taxonomist, but I am sure there are a whole lot more.

To be more specific, the context is there is a galactic warehouse full of books and documents and journal articles, and other media resources, and these are going to be searched and annotated, so that the annotated parts can be used in reports.

It's not really analysis, and it's not "research" since it has no specific topic in mind -- it's more cataloguing what the parts of interest are of these documents, (where "interest" is defined by what the document is in itself), putting them into categories, and recording a reference to these annotations in a big card system. The entries in that card system can then be used say in making other resources in future. With proper attribution back to the source.

Kind of like a massive citation project -- so the people who go through and make all these citations / annotations, what would they be called? A cluster of terms is more useful than one because I am not just seeking "an answer" I am trying to think more deeply about what that role is exactly.

Comment: Can you provide more context?  As it stands you could get answers from taxonomist to ontologist to librarian to secretary.

Comment: Good point. Okay -- I will edit and try to provide more context. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Archivist*.

You could use synonyms, but that's the best word based on your description.  Otherwise see @Jim's comment for alternatives.